Buddhism and Pandemics
I had a quick question in regards to the Buddhist view on the recent pandemic.
What would the stance be of a Buddhist towards the government tactics of losing jobs if not vaccinated, being locked down etc and mandating the vaccine?
Should we be free to choose based on our personal educated opinion or is it a case of always following authoritative orders even if they can be seen as detrimental by a certain percentage of the population?
Would compassion, understanding be the best answer towards all sides?
Would it make you 'not a Buddhist' if you choose a certain view?
Regards,
Nik

The "stance" towards obeying the government (e.g. lockdowns) is one thing -- towards agreeing with "government tactics" (re. "losing jobs") is another. This seems to be mostly a "political" question. You're asking about "the Buddhist view" which may be "opinion" -- questions on this site are more normally about Buddhist doctrine or practice.

What would the stance be of a Buddhist
The criteria for deciding what is worth saying is from MN 58 -- which the Buddha said to a "prince", so maybe it's right to apply to a government's speech too.
It includes:

In the case of words that the Tathagata knows to be factual, true, beneficial, but unendearing & disagreeable to others, he has a sense of the proper time for saying them.

Perhaps a Buddhist's "stance" on that speech might depend on whether they considered it "factual" etc.
Should we be free to choose based on our personal educated opinion
I suppose that generally Buddhism isn't coercive, but a government might be.
There's also a sometimes a distinction to make between "freedom" and "liberty" -- if you were conscripted to be a soldier for example, perhaps you might remain "free" but not "at liberty" to refuse conscription, as a "conscientious objector".
is it a case of always following authoritative orders
Having read some suttas and spent a while on this site, I find that I apply the "middle way" i.e. "avoiding both extremes" sometimes to questions like this.
When you ask, "Is it always this, or is it always that?", then the answer might be "yeah no, not always" -- an "order to kill" being one (extreme) example, in this essay Getting the Message a monk takes an uncompromising view towards literally killing, even for a government.
Would compassion, understanding be the best answer towards all sides?
That's recommended as a Buddhist's attitude towards other individuals:

Brahmaviharas

According to Nyanaponika Thera in this essay:

These four attitudes are said to be excellent or sublime because they are the right or ideal way of conduct towards living beings (sattesu samma patipatti). They provide, in fact, the answer to all situations arising from social contact.

It might not follow that laissez-faire, permissiveness, is always the right behaviour of parents or governments.

Now at that time a baby boy was lying face-up on the prince's lap. So the Blessed One said to the prince, "What do you think, prince: If this young boy, through your own negligence or that of the nurse, were to take a stick or a piece of gravel into its mouth, what would you do?"
"I would take it out, lord. If I couldn't get it out right away, then holding its head in my left hand and crooking a finger of my right, I would take it out, even if it meant drawing blood. Why is that? Because I have sympathy for the young boy."


I see you might use an "argument" like:

You should be compassionate
Therefore you should respect another's educated opinion
Therefore the government shouldn't require them to obey the government's policy

I don't like applying "extremist" speech to political topics, e.g. you could add "always" to the first two sentences above, and "never" to the third.
Would it make you 'not a Buddhist' if you choose a certain view?
That might be:

A question about whether you can and should "identify as a Buddhist"
A "no true Scotsman" logical fallacy
A question about "views" (and disputes) in general
A political question about the role and powers of government


FYI I'm from Ontario, where my doctor has "always" asked me to get the annual flu vaccine, even though (as a healthy adult) I never needed it. Doing so is Ontario policy (and I'm told that it's a bit unusual among health authorities), to improve "herd immunity" -- i.e. to reduce the prevalence of flu, to benefit society and especially those who are "at risk" (e.g. the elderly, and infants, and so on).
I always agreed to, "freely" -- for the sake of "the herd"!
That's not especially to do with Buddhism though -- maybe morality in general, and/or my "educated opinion" of the medical advice.

Buddhism teaches to understand causes & effects, which includes to understand the consequences of your actions. If your government mandates a vaccine (regardless its effectiveness & safety) and you choose not to comply, you should be prepared to face the consequences.
For example, in my country, due to the laws:

My older sister chose to leave her normal (close client contact) job.

My younger sister kept her job because (when illegally threatened by her employer) I wrote a legal submission why her employer was forbidden to end her employment.


None of our family took the needle because we each independently regarded the needle as harmful & unbeneficial. As Buddhists, our duty is to act in ways that are not harmful & are beneficial. Therefore, about these matters, Buddhism says:


Those who see something to fear where there is nothing to fear, and see nothing to fear where there is something to fear — upholding
false views, they go to states of woe.

Those who imagine evil where there is none, and do not see evil where it is — upholding false views, they go to states of woe.

Those who discern the wrong as wrong and the right as right — upholding right views, they go to realms of bliss.


Dhammapada


Generally speaking, the Buddhist stance on these things is that sometimes it is appropriate to inflict a temporary discomfort on someone for the sake of their greater long-term good.
In the suttas the Buddha never dumbs this principle down to some kind of simplistic formula, instead he always emphasizes the importance of using wisdom when making decisions that involve ethical contradictions. That said, from the examples and similes used by the Buddha, the overall pattern seems pretty clear: the long term benefit trumps short term discomfort, especially in life-and-death situations, e.g. being shot by a poisonous arrow.
At the same time, in suttas we can see numerous indications of Buddha trying to avoid stirring unnecessary resistance in people he's trying to help, knowing that people often react emotionally and their negative reactions can be counterproductive to what he is trying to achieve.
In Mahayana, this principle is taken even further than in the Early Buddhism. There we often see Buddhist mentors not shy away from taking advantage of student's confusion to help them into what they know is the right direction. This is known as Upaya or skillful means, exemplified by the parable of the children in the burning house. In numerous anecdotes Mahayana teachers are shown being quite brutal with their students, ruthlessly provoking mental/emotional anguish and even physical pain in the name of helping their students to break through.
Based on this, overall, we can say that the government resorting to arm-wrestling in situations like the global pandemic, for the greater good of the people, is most likely not considered inappropriate from the Buddhist perspective. That said, every specific policy decision should be evaluated individually to see if the amount of force and discomfort is commensurate with the sought long-term benefit.
